# A simpler proof that every spanning list in $V$ can be reduced to a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra Done Right, the proof that every spanning list in $V$ can be reduced to a basis of $V$ seems to just be an application of the Linear Dependence Lemma.

I have attached Axler's proof below.

The proof I had in mind was as follows:
If 0 is in the spanning list, then remove it.
If the remaining spanning list is linearly independent, the it is a basis of $V$, so we are done. If the spanning list if linearly dependent, then by the linear dependence lemma we can remove a term from the spanning list without altering the span. By repeating this process, we can very simply reduce a spanning list to a basis. I find this much more intuitive and it uses a result that has already been proved early in the text.

Does this proof work, and if it does, why does Axler chose to use the other proof? Does it display something important that my proof doesn't?

Axlers proof:

[image: 1]

Comment: "I have attached Axler's proof below."  ...  Have you?

Comment: it didn't do right

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought I did, let me fix that...

Comment: Are you assuming that you start with a *finite* dimensional vector space *and* a *finite* spanning set? What if your spanning set is infinite? You can only remove a countable subset thereof, and that might not do it. For instance, consider the spanning set consisting of all positive reals, for the vector space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Axler's proof also assumes a finite spanning list.

Comment: Okay, then. Your argument works in that setting. Why does Axler do this instead? Well, first, he is not merely proving the theorem, he is giving you an *algorithm* for finding the basis. You, on the other hand, have not provided an algorithm (if we both follow your instructions, we may end up with different bases; if we follow Axler's, we will both end up with the same basis). And second, Axler's argument generalizes to well-ordered infinite spanning sets, whereas yours does not.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure "simpler" is accurate. Certainly "different", but both arguments strike me as having about the same level of complexity to tham.

Comment: I see. With regards to your first point, could I simply specify to use the linear dependence lemma starting with the leftmost or rightmost element in the list, and the moving right or left from there, respectively? I haven't "learned of well-ordered infinite spanning sets" yet, but when I do, I will try to remember to come back to your comment! Thank you!

Comment: No, that would not necessarily work, since there may be multiple ways of "discovering" the linear dependence. Say you specify the leftmost, and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we start with $(1,0)$, $(3,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(3,1)$. Then we could say "Linearly dependent because $3(1,0) + 0(3,0)+(0,1) - (3,1)=(0,0)$", so we remove $(1,0)$. But we could also say. "linearly dependent because $0(1,0)+(3,1)+(0,1)-(3,1)=(0,0)$", so this time we remove $(3,0)$ instead...

Comment: In my opinion, the two proofs are quite similar. Both proofs use the same idea of removing vectors that are in the span of the remaining vectors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't see what you mean... if the list of vectors were $((1,0) , (3,0), (0,1), (3,1))$ and we were to cut down the list starting from the left, then $(3, 0)$ would be removed first because $(1, 0) \neq 0$ and $(3, 0) \in$ span$( (1, 0) )$.

Comment: @HenryYan: Then you are just using the algorithm that Axler proposed. I thought you wanted to use the lemma that says that if it is linearly dependent, one of the vectors is a linear combination of the rest, which means finding a nontrivial linear combination, and then using that to write one of the vectors in terms of the rest. By "leftmost" I assumed you mean "find a nontrivial linear combination, and use that to express the leftmost vector with nonzero coefficient as a linear combination of the rest, and remove it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading about your proof and I think that it is the same idea. First of all, he's speaking about finite set and so finite dimensional vector space, hence there aren't problem with the finitness of the process. The "differences" are two. One: Axler doesn't worry about remove $0$ from the list but only to remove $v_1$ if it is zero. Because during the rest of the process if there is a zero it will be remove from the list automatically. The second difference is the order of remotion. Your proof is not formal. In other word your proof it's not an algorhitm, you don't say "how to do" but "what to do". I don't know if it's clear. To sum up, Axler's process is a process that must end in a finite number of steps and it concretize your idea.

Comment: It is also a deterministic process with no choices in it (which is what makes it algorithmic). If all we do is find *a* vector that is a linear combination of others in the set and remove it, then that is not deterministic.