# Alternate proof of every spanning list of a vector space containing a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is essentially the same as [A simpler proof that every spanning list in $V$ can be reduced to a basis of $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215371/a-simpler-proof-that-every-spanning-list-in-v-can-be-reduced-to-a-basis-of-v). I also attached Axler's proof below (a pdf can also be found on his official website). I am not sure if the following is a valid proof:

My proof:

Step 1: Let $L = v_1, \dots, v_m$ span $V$. If $L$ is linearly independent, we are done. If not, by the Linear Dependence Lemma, we can remove a vector from $L$ without affecting the span. Thus our new list is $L^1 = v_1^1, v_2^1, \dots, v_{m-1}^1$.

Step k: Let $L^{k-1} = v_1^{k-1}, \dots, v_{m-(k-1)}^{k-1}$ span $V$. If $L^{k-1}$ is linearly independent, we are done. If not, we can remove a vector without affecting the span, giving new list $L^{k} = v_1^{k}, \dots, v_{m-k}^{k}$.

We have only removed vectors that do not affect the span. Since there can be at most $m$ steps (since by definition $\emptyset$ is linearly independent), the process terminates. The process terminates if $L^k$ is linearly independent. (Between these two sentences, I am confused.) Thus eventually $L$ becomes linearly independent.

END OF PROOF

QUESTION: We know the process terminates if $L^k$ is linearly independent. However, we do NOT know that the process terminates **only if** $L^k$ is linearly independent. So is this even a valid proof?

[Axler's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSFji.jpg)

Comment: Are you concerned that the process might also terminate if we drop dead while in the middle of it, kinda like Paul Erdos?

Comment: To be more explicit: If $L^k$ still spans $V$, and is not linearly independent, then there is some $v_i$ that can be written as a linear combination of the others, meaning that the others still span the vector space. Thus we do too know that the process terminates only if $L^k$ is linearly independent.